# iOS Predicate for RLMLinkingObjects (Realm)

Tags: ios, realm

I have linking object in my category.

```
@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects *relatedAttachments;
```

I only want to take category if it have relatedAttachments. I try with this.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"relatedAttachments.count > 0"]];

self.categories = [[Category objectsWithPredicate:pred] sortedResultsUsingProperty:@"id" ascending:YES];
```

I got error like this.

> RLMPrecondition(property, @"Invalid property name",

So I try with other.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"relatedAttachments.count!=nil"]];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"relatedAttachments.count!=NULL"]];
```

But it is still not okay. How shall I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a predicate like:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relatedAttachments.@count > 0"];
```

`@count` is a collection operator that evaluates to the number of elements in the collection it appears to the right of.